# »Sowie« im Kontext mit Zulassungsvorraussetzungen

Tags: word-usage, conjunction

Ich bin gerade auf einen Lehrgang mit Zulassungsvoraussetzungen gestoßen, bei denen ich mir nicht ganz sicher bin, was gemeint ist.

> Der Lehrgang richtet sich auch an AbsolventInnen der IHK Weiter- bildungsprogramme Betriebswirt, Technischer Betriebswirt, sowie operativer oder strategischer IT Professional
>   (sic)

Von meinem Verständnis her heißt das, dass man eine der vier Qualifikationen und nicht einen (technischen) Betriebswirt und den operativen oder strategischen Professional braucht.

Ich frage deshalb, da ich im ersten Moment *sowie* als *auch* gelesen habe und jetzt verunsichert bin.

Comment: Für _sowie_ in der Bedeutung _und_ (in Aufzählungen) gelten dieselben Kommaregeln wie bei _und;_ d. h., das Komma vor _sowie_ in der Broschüre der IHK ist falsch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"sowie" wird vom [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sowie#Bedeutung1) u.a. so definert:

> dient der Verknüpfung von Gliedern einer Aufzählung; und [außerdem], und auch, wie auch

In Deinem Beispiel werden einfach die 4 IHK-Bildungsprogramme aufgelistet, für deren Absolventen der Lehrgang gedacht ist.

Comment: macht auch eigentlich nur so Sinn