# Begleiten die Konjunktionen "sobald" und "sowie" einen Haupt- oder Nebensatz?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case, conjunction

Ich habe die folgende Nutzung gesehen, wo *sobald* bzw. *sowie* einen Nebensatz einleitet:

> Wir werden euch besuchen, **sobald/sowie** die Ferien zu Ende sind.

Und ich habe auch die folgende Verwendung gesehen, wo *sowie* ein Teil des Satzes ist:

> Durchführung und Auswertung von LiSe-DaZ **sowie** zur Ableitung von Fördermaßnahmen in der jeweiligen Situation ihrer Anwendungspraxis geklärt werden.

Und wird *sowie* mit Dativ oder Genitiv verwendet?

> Der Saunabesuch hat dem Kind sowie der ganzen Familie gut getan.

Ist *der Familie* im Dativ oder im Genitiv?

EDIT

Auch nach dem Lesen der bisherigen Antworten, kann ich nicht erkennen, warum die Familie im Genitiv oder Dativ ist. Wenn es sich um eine kopulative Konjunktion handelt, wie kommt es, dass es *der Familie* lautet.

Bedeutet kopulative Konjunktion nicht, dass die Objekte gleichberechtigt sind?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/sowie-im-kontext-mit-zulassungsvorraussetzungen

Comment: Der zweite Beispielsatz ist kein richtiger Satz oder noch nicht einmal etwas Ähnliches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Sowie](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sowie)* hat zwei Bedeutungen:

> umgangssprachlich: sobald als, gleich wenn, in dem Augenblick
> vergleichend, aufzählend: wie auch, und außerdem

Die erste Verwendung entspricht deinem ersten Satz. Diese ist mir zwar nicht geläufig, weswegen ich hier immer zu *sobald* greifen würde. In jedem Fall ist die Funktion eine [temporale Konjunktion](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/temporal.html) von zwei Satzteilen, dem Hauptsatz und dem Nebensatz. Es ist eine untergeordnete Konjunktion. Dabei wird im Nebensatz angefügt, zu welchem Zeitpunkt das im Hauptsatz genannte geschehen wird; beziehungsweise welches Ereignis eintreten muss. Im Englischen entspricht dies *as soon as*.

Der zweite Anwendungsfall ist eine [kopulative Konjunktion](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/kopulativ.html), jedoch werden hier nur Wörter oder Wortgruppen verbunden. Es ist eine nebengeordnete Konjunktion. Es wird im Wesentlichen in einer Aufzählung verwendet, wobei in deinem Beispiel die Aufzählung nur aus zwei Objekten besteht. Man könnte auch einfach nur *und* verwenden, jedoch legt *sowie* eine stärkere Betonung auf das letzte Glied der Kette.
Es entspricht dem englischen *as well as*.

Wie in der anderen Antwort schon gesagt, hat *sowie* keinen direkten Bezug auf den Kasus. Beide Wörter, also das vor und das nach *sowie* stehen im gleichen Kasus, nämlich dem, der durch das Verb verlangt wird.
Beispiele:

> Nominativ: Das Kind sowie die Eltern gehen in die Sauna.
> Akkusativ: Ich hab das Kind sowie die Eltern gesehen.
> Dativ: Der Saunabesuch hat dem Kind sowie den Eltern gut getan.
> Genitiv: Das Bild des Kindes sowie der Eltern steht auf dem Regal.

Dein Beispiel steht im Dativ.

> **Jemandem**<sub>Dat.</sub> tut etwas<sub>Akk.</sub> gut
>
> [Der Saunabesuch]<sub>Akk.</sub> [hat] [dem Kind und/sowie den Eltern]<sub>Dativ</sub> [gut getan].

Comment: Ich habe Ihre Antwort mit großem Interesse gelesen. Ich kann nicht vorstellen, warum die Familie im Genitiv oder Dativ ist. Wenn das eine kopulative Konjunktion zwischen zwei Teilen ist, wie kommt das? Warum ''der Familie''(?) das macht kein Sinn!

Comment: Ordnet nicht die kopulative Konjunktion ''sowie'' gleichberechtigt miteinander?

Comment: Der Dativ kommt von "guttun": "Der Saunabesuch hat *dem Kind* gut getan, und er hat auch *der ganzen Familie* gut getan".

Answer (score 2):

*Sowie* als einfaches Bindewort heißt einfach *und auch*. Es ist keine Präposition mit einem bestimmten Fall. Nach dem Bindewort kann jeder Fall stehen, je nach Verwendung im Satz.

*Sowie* kann auch eine Nebensatz-Einleitung sein. Betont Gleichzeitigkeit. Das Verb steht im Nebensatz in Endstellung.

Siehe auch: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sowie

Comment: Was passiert, wenn ich ''sowie'' mit dem Dativ oder Genitiv?

Comment: Wie gesagt, "sowie" ist keine Präposition, es heißt einfach "und (auch)".

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt im Deutschen *nebenordnende* (solche, die gleichberechtigte Satzteile, also z.B. zwei Hauptsätze oder zwei Nebensätze miteinander verbinden) und *unterordnende* (also solche, die Haupt- und Nebensatz miteinander verbinden) Konjunktionen.

*Sowie* besitzt zwei Bedeutungen und fällt mit jeder in eine der beiden Klassen:

1. *sowie* im Sinne von "und" ist eine nebenordnende Konjunktion und verbindet z.B zwei Hauptsatzbestandteile miteinander:

   > Beamte sowie Angestellte des öffentlichen Dienstes erhalten die Sonderleistungen des Staates als Arbeitgeber

   Hier läßt sich *sowie* einfach durch "und" ersetzen. Da wir keinen Nebensatz haben, steht da auch kein Komma.
2. *sowie* im Sinne von "sobald" ist eine unterordnende Konjunktion und leitet einen temporalen Nebensatz ein:

   > Sowie er angekommen war, suchte er Bekanntschaften unter den Damen des Ortes

   Weil wir einen Nebensatz haben, staht da auch ein Komma.

*sobald* ist eine unterordnende Konjunktion und leitet immer einen Nebensatz ein.

Zu deiner zweiten Frage: Konjunktionen haben eigentlich keine Auswirkungen auf den Fall - Dieser wird von anderen Satzbestandteilen regiert, in deinem Beispiel vom Verb: *gutgehen* fordert ganz einfach den Dativ.